# Problema na consulta PHP + MySQL usando LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, query, operador-like

Boa tarde galera, recentemente em um dos meus projetos surgiu um problema e espero que vocês possam me ajudar.

Para entender melhor o site é um site de consultas na área de saúde, como clínicas, cardiologia, urologia, etc. Algumas clínicas podem pertencer a duas categorias ao mesmo tempo, como "Clínica" e "Cardiologia" fiz a consulta da seguinte maneira:

```
$url.= ' AND t.areadasaude LIKE "%'.$especialidadesaude.'%"';
```

O problema é, a categoria Cardiologia pertence ao id = 1, a cardiologia pertence ao id = 19, como o LIKE consulta tudo que esta dentro da tabela todos os resultados que estão dentro da categoria 19 estão aparecendo na categoria 1 isso porque o LIKE pega o numero 1 do id 19. Como eu faço para o LIKE pegar 100% do que for marcado?

Observação: Caso eu marque duas categorias, no banco de dados é registrado da seguinte maneira: `["1","19"]`, devemos considerar na consulta tbm quando tiver mais de uma categoria marcada. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Like não é pra isso.

Answer (score 2):

que tal tentar usar t.areadasaude IN ('1', '19') ao invés de LIKE

Comment: Eu não posso fixar os valores exatos pois se trata de uma consulta com varias categorias, tanto pode ser 1, quanto 2, 5, 10, ou ["10","20"] =/ o valores 1 e 19 foi apenas figurativo

Comment: Entendo que não pode ser fixo, só dei um exemplo do IN. Nesse caso você tem que fazer algo em seu código que pegue esses valores e coloque em uma variável já formatada para usar no IN().

Answer (score 0):

Que valor vem nessa variável $especialidadesaude e de que forma está armazenado nesse campo 'areasaude'?
Se for os ids separados por espaço (ou outro caractere) você pode usar o slipt:

```
$ids = split(' ', $especialidadesaude);
```

poderia retornar os valores do campo no banco, se estiverem armazenados separados por vírgula tmb e fazer o split dele e comparar os vetores;

Se o campo 'areasaude' no banco possuir um só valor a consulta ficaria assim:

```
$url.= ' AND t.areadasaude IN($ids)';
```

Mas se os ids das categorias relacionadas estiverem sendo armazenados em um campo creio que isso não seja o ideal mas sim ter um relacionamento **n:m** onde haveria uma tabela com os ids das duas tabelas. Nesse caso a consulta ficaria assim (não testei a consulta):

```
SELECT c.* FROM categorias c 
INNER JOIN clinicas_x_categorias cxc ON c.idCat = tbs.idCat
WHERE cxc.idCat IN($ids)
GROUP BY c.idCat
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tab_consul[0] = "10";
$tab_consul[1] = "8";
$tab_consul[2] = "14";

// Collar tudo junto, com "," entre os dados
$string_in = implode(",",$tab_consul);
// Uso de IN para ter os valores de areadasaude que estão na lista
$url.= ' AND t.areadasaude IN(".$string_in.")";
```